# Passing data between build steps in Jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'd like to do something along the lines of:

This is overly simple and just demonstrates what I'd like to do. Basically, I want to be able to store and access variables within a single job scope between multiple build steps. Also, I can get around by storing the data to a file and reading it later, but I'd like something easier and less 'hacky'

Build Step #1 - Execute shell

```
$START=timestamp
```

Build Step #2 - Run another job

Build Step #3 - Execute Shell

```
$END=timestamp
TIME_LAPSED=$END-$START
(post lapsed time somewhere)
```

Answer (score 33):

One thing remains between shells: the workspace.
Simple and stupid solution: use file(s)!

Huge additional advantage: it works when you split your job in several jobs and use the Clone Workspace plugin

**Build Step #1 - Execute shell**

```
START=timestamp
...
echo $START > env_start.txt
```

**...**

**Build Step #3 - Execute Shell**

```
START=`cat env_start.txt`
END=timestamp
TIME_LAPSED=$END-$START
```

Comment: If you use the env variable in conditions, i.e. check if defined or empty, you might want to use the echo option `-n` to prevent having a file filled with a blank line: `echo -n $START > env_start.txt` then in step 3 `if [ -s env_start.txt ]; then echo "Unset" ; fi`

Answer (score 12):

If you are using the declarative pipeline syntax defining a variable in the `environment` section and using a `script` step to set its value may be useful.

I'm doing something like this with a declarative pipeline and it works for passing a variable (both inside one stage and between stages):

```
pipeline {
        agent any
        environment {
            variable = ''
        }
        stages {
            stage('Some stage') { 
                steps {
                    script {
                        if (some condition){
                            variable = 'some value'
                        } else { variable = 'else value' }
                    }                
                    sh '${somepath}/bin/script ' + 
                        "-parameter=${variable}"
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('Dummy print') {
                steps {
                    sh "echo ${variable}"
                }
            }
[...]
```

Comment: You can also in Stage steps set or update a env variable with   env.myvar=„new-value“

Comment: This only works for strings.  Of course, you can represent nearly anything as a string but it isn't that convenient.

Answer (score 7):

We use inject environment variables plugin extensively and it works great.
The solution is:

1. Set your variable myenv=value1
2. print to file in workspace: echo "myenv=$myenv" > tmp.myenv
3. Inject after every change: Use envinject to read environment from file tmp.myenv -> myenv is now known as part of the job environment.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

@Gurubaran's solution works for me, you need to install "[Environment Injector](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)" plugin in jenkins, then

Step1:
use shell/powershell/windows batch/etc. to create generate a properties(key=value) file. for example: the file path is $WORKSPACE/env.properties.

Step2:
Add an "Inject environment variables" component and set "Properties File Path" to $WORKSPACE/env.properties

After Step2:
You can use these environment variables in the following steps.

Example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 3):

One way to work with Jenkins variables is to use `jenkins-cli.jar` in the build step, it takes some work but this will add `FOO=1` in the parameters list, since it's running in a build step it knows which build to set the parameter for.

```
java -jar ${JENKINS_HOME}/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s ${JENKINS_URL} set-build-parameter FOO 1
```

Comment: Nice solution! It works if the user has _overall-read_, _job-read_ and _run-update_ permissions.

Comment: `set-build-parameter` does not work anymore... looks deprecated

Answer (score 3):

None of:

- *String Parameter* of a *Parameterized Build*
- pre-build *Inject environment variables to the build process*
- in-build step *Inject environment variables*

works (as of v1.656). You are able to read each of them, of course, but new values that are assigned to them are not available in subsequent build steps.

Hence, JediMasterCoder's answer and handling via file like Destroyica's are the only options so far.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins allows you to inject environment variables to the build process. Maybe all you have to do is Inject the Start time and End Time as environment variables and access them across your build steps.
[image]

Comment: Does this give me the ability to do inject during the numerous build steps? Ie can I dynamically set these at the time the data is available. Remember, I'm only showing start/stop times as an example. There are many things I want to do beyond just this.

Comment: @jcol : I do not think you can inject the env variables after you have set them in the "Build Environment" Phase. But you would be able to manipulate them when the data becomes available.

Comment: Is this a built-in functionality? Or a plugin is needed? Edit: this plugin is needed: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin

Comment: I had the same idea – and even more, I tried it. It doesn't work. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37013519/1744774).

Comment: 2021 april - https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/ - The current version of this plugin contains a vulnerability: Exposure of sensitive build variables stored by EnvInject 1.90 and earlier

Answer (score 0):

On top of what @Gurubaran suggested (which is what I'd do if had no other option), I'd just opt for joining the build steps to a single one, which will greatly simplify this need.
You will need to care for the error handling logic and exit conditions, but your environment will be solid!

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ehh, this doesn't solve my problem. I have external jobs between my shell build steps. In the example given above, I want to calculate dynamic factors at different points of the build. Having numerous jobs allows me to independently run various steps as well as version contorl them individually for different reasons.

Answer (score 0):

For sharing a few variables, I made the next code snippet.

In the first execute shell:

```bash
cat <<EOF > "$WORKSPACE"/export_vars.sh
export VERSION="$VERSION"
export PROJECT_NAME="$PROJECT_NAME"
export REPOSITORY="$REPOSITORY"
EOF
```

In the second execute shell:

```bash
# source "$WORKSPACE"/export_vars.sh don't worked for me
. "$WORKSPACE"/export_vars.sh
```