# How to export a persistent environment variable from execute shell step in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

If I have multiple execute shell steps in a Jenkins build, how can I create an environment variable in a particular execute shell step that will still be available in a subsequent execute shell steps and in plugin fields? I specifically want to use the variable in the formatted email plugin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between build steps in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366808/passing-data-between-build-steps-in-jenkins)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879733/jenkinsfile-declarative-pipeline-defining-dynamic-env-vars/43881731#43881731

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, you can always put the variables into a file , make that file and artifact which will be delivered to the next stage and then source that file in the next stage

Comment: I want to use the variable in a plugin field, that only can access environment variables.

Comment: @sakurashinken Did you follow the link I gave you in my comment to your question? There _is_ an answer apart from handling this via a file.

Comment: I see that, but its cumbersome. I'll have to figure out something else.