# Pass variables between Jenkins stages

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to pass a variable which I read in stage A towards stage B somehow. I see in some examples that people write it to a file, but I guess that is not really a nice solution. I tried writing it to an environment variable, but I'm not really successful on that. How can I set it up properly?

To get it working I tried a lot of things and read that I should use the """ instead of ''' to start a shell and escape those variables to `\${foo}` for example.

Below is what I have as a pipeline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {

    agent { node { label 'php71' } }

    environment {
        packageName='my-package'
        packageVersion=''
        groupId='vznl'
        nexus_endpoint='http://nexus.devtools.io'
        nexus_username='jenkins'
        nexus_password='J3nkins'
    }

    stages{

        // Package dependencies
        stage('Install dependencies') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    echo Skip composer installation
                    #composer install  --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-interaction
                '''
            }
        }

        // Unit tests
        stage('Unit Tests') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    echo Running PHP code coverage tests...
                    #composer test
                '''
            }
        }

        // Create artifact
        stage('Package') {
            steps {
                echo 'Create package refs'
                sh """
                    mkdir -p ./build/zpk
                    VERSIONTAG=\$(grep 'version' composer.json)
                    REGEX='"version": "([0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)"'
                    if [[ \${VERSIONTAG} =~ \${REGEX} ]]
                    then
                        env.packageVersion=\${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
                        /usr/bin/zs-client packZpk --folder=. --destination=./build/zpk --name=${env.packageName}-${env.packageVersion}.zpk --version=${env.packageVersion}
                    else
                        echo "No version found!"
                        exit 1
                    fi
                """
            }
        }

        // Publish ZPK package to Nexus
        stage('Publish packages') {
            steps {
                echo "Publish ZPK Package"
                sh "curl -u ${env.nexus_username}:${env.nexus_password} --upload-file ./build/zpk/${env.packageName}-${env.packageVersion}.zpk ${env.nexus_endpoint}/repository/zpk-packages/${groupId}/${env.packageName}-${env.packageVersion}.zpk"
                archive includes: './build/**/*.{zpk,rpm,deb}'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the `packageVersion` which I read from stage *Package* needs to be used in stage *Publish* as well.

Overall tips against the pipeline are of course always welcome as well.

Comment: Try "env variable" plugin it might be help you

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44101004/6090676 (it happens to be reading from a file to set the variable, but you could set it any way you want).

Comment: try reusing node with `reuseNode true` when defining agent

Comment: @toske, problem is not the reuse of the node but the assignment of variables since there is only 1 node. Problem is when i run above command i receive this as output: `+ env.packageVersion=1.71.0
/var/lib/jenkins-slave/workspace/l_omnius-vf-nl-code_develop-IFXWAOWKAO7SA3MSTIVC4SLDHWGNQ63ALTYVVLGNHRM6SYQNYZTA@tmp/durable-acda6886/script.sh: line 9: env.packageVersion=1.71.0: command not found`

The solution of writing to file is very evil imo?

Comment: @Dirkos answered below, solution bit better than writing to file, still makes memory space bit dirty and not able to parellize. You could write to file and `stash` / `unstash` - this would make it thread safe.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A problem in your code is that you are assigning version of environment variable within the `sh` step. This step will execute in its own isolated process, inheriting parent process environment variables.

However, the only way of passing data back to the parent is through `STDOUT/STDERR` or exit code. As you want a string value, it is best to echo version from the `sh` step and assign it to a variable within the `script` context.

If you reuse the node, the script context will persist, and variables will be available in the subsequent stage. A working example is below. Note that any try to put this within a `parallel` block can be of failure, as the version information variable can be written to by multiple processes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

pipeline {

    environment {
        AGENT_INFO = ''
    }

    agent {
        docker {
            image 'alpine'
            reuseNode true
        }
    }

    stages {

        stage('Collect agent info'){
            steps {
                echo "Current agent  info: ${env.AGENT_INFO}"
                script {
                    def agentInfo = sh script:'uname -a', returnStdout: true
                    println "Agent info within script: ${agentInfo}"
                    AGENT_INFO = agentInfo.replace("/n", "")
                    env.AGENT_INFO = AGENT_INFO
                }
            }
        }

        stage("Print agent info"){
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Collected agent info: ${AGENT_INFO}"
                    echo "Environment agent info: ${env.AGENT_INFO}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will work if stages were runned with different agents ? I'll try

Comment: @codeGeass I wouldn't expect it to work on different agents

Comment: Yes I did but I don't put the variable as an Environment variable in Environment block but as a variable:  def myVar = ...  before the pipeline block, and then when use it in different stages, it works fine.

Comment: I quite like this solution, but you can also use files for passing variables. 
You could  <<sh 'echo hello > hello.txt' >> and then "readFile('hello.txt')

Comment: Perfect solution with explanation. Saved my time.

Answer (score 4):

Another option which doesn't involve using `script`, but is just declarative, is to stash things in a little temporary environment file.

You can then use this stash (like a temporary cache that only lives for the run) if the workload is sprayed out across parallel or distributed nodes as needed.

Something like:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('first stage') {
            steps {
                // Write out any environment variables you like to a temporary file
                sh 'echo export FOO=baz > myenv'

                // Stash away for later use
                stash 'myenv'
            }
        }

        stage ("later stage") {
            steps {

                // Unstash the temporary file and apply it
                unstash 'myenv'

                // use the unstashed vars
                sh 'source myenv && echo $FOO'

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since every "sh" block is executed in a different shell process, you cannot source first and then use a variable in a different "sh" command.

You could do it in the same one though. 

sh 'source myenv ; echo $FOO'

Comment: Remark that you don't need to prefix "./" in order to SOURCE a file into the current shell. You need that for executing commands when "." is not in the current path, but "source" simply reads the given file.