# How can I capture the exit code of a job's "Execute shell" build step for use later in a pipeline?

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy

I have a pipeline script that executes a build as one of its steps. Let's say it looks like this:

```
pipeline{
    stages {
        stage('Build'){
            steps{
                node('master'){
                    build job: 'my_build'
                }
            }
        }
        (other stages.........)
    }
}
```

Occasionally, that step ("Build") fails. I have a shell script in the "Build" job (an "Execute shell" step) that exits with a certain return code that I then exit the step with, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
./my_build_script.sh
exit $?
```

The problem is, I'm not sure how to capture *that* exit code for use later in the pipeline.

What I'd like to achieve is *only retrying the build on a particular exit code from that "Execute shell" step*.

Answer (score 1):

By storing in variable?

```
./my_build_script.sh
get_status=$?
```

#### Now you can do something with variable: $get_status

Comment: Will that variable be available at the pipeline script-level? Say, in another stage in the pipeline, I wanted to say something like `when { expression { $get_status == 200 } }`.

Comment: Yes, see this link  [pass-variables-between-stages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099851/how-do-i-pass-variables-between-stages-in-a-declarative-jenkins-pipeline)

Comment: In that example, the variable is set at the pipeline level, not the "Execute shell" level down in the job that the pipeline runs.

Comment: The other easiest way, is to save variable value in file:
`echo $get_status > status_file.txt`

And you can get this file everywhere in your pipeline.

In other stage you will be able to do:
`get_status=$(cat status_file.txt)`

Comment: Sure, that works, but it's not a very elegant solution (clutters disk space, I/O). I'll keep looking.

Comment: Of course!
there are also memory I/O;, like:
`export $get_status` and it will be your linux session temporarily env variable