# Jenkins pipeline "when" condition with sh defined variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm trying to create a Jenkins pipeline where I in my first stage I define a variable in a sh shell script.
Then I want to run the next stages using a "when" condition depending on the previous defined variable.

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'php71' }
    stages {
        stage('Prepare CI...') {
            steps{
                sh '''
                    # Get the comment that was made on the PR
                    COMMENT=`echo $payload | jq .comment.body | tr -d '"'`
                    if [ "$COMMENT" = ":repeat: Jenkins" ]; then
                        BUILD="build"
                    fi
                '''
            }
        }
        stage('Build Pre Envrionment') {
            agent { label 'php71' }
            when {
                expression { return $BUILD == "build" }
            }
            steps('Build') {
                sh '''
                    echo $BUILD
                    echo $COMMENT
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me an error:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: $BUILD for class: groovy.lang.Binding

How can I do it? Is it possible?
Thank you!

Comment: I've found some way of doing this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099851/how-do-i-pass-variables-between-stages-in-a-declarative-jenkins-pipeline

Comment: I'm just trying to find a better solution without having to use a file...

Answer (score 1):

Probably use Jenkins scripted pipeline which is more flexible than declarative.
Print the value in the sh script and use returnStdout to make it available to the pipeline script.  See [How to do I get the output of a shell command executed using into a variable from Jenkinsfile (groovy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547680/how-to-do-i-get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-executed-using-into-a-variable-fro/53254497#53254497) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the variable `BUILD` is only available within the `sh` block. but to use it later in the `when` block it must be known globally in the pipeline. This is possible if you define `BUILD` in the `environment` block on `pipeline` level. A possible solution for your problem see here:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'php71' }
    environment {
        COMMENT=sh(script: '''# Get the comment that was made on the PR
                    echo $payload | jq .comment.body | tr -d '"'
                ''', returnStdout: true).trim()
        BUILD=sh(script: '''# Get the comment that was made on the PR
                    COMMENT=`echo $payload | jq .comment.body | tr -d '"'`
                    if [ "$COMMENT" = ":repeat: Jenkins" ]; then
                        echo "build"
                    fi
                ''', returnStdout: true).trim()
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build Pre Envrionment') {
            agent { label 'php71' }
            when {
                expression { return env.BUILD == "build" }
            }
            steps('Build') {
                sh '''
                    echo $BUILD
                    echo $COMMENT
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```