# How to pass user input into jenkins function invocation?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have this jenkins stage:

```
    stage('Run tests?') {
        agent none
        steps {
          script {
            TESTS = input message: 'User input required', parameters: [
              choice(name: 'Run Tests', choices: 'yes\nno', description: 'Run unit and e2e tests?')]
          }
        }
    }
```

and below I do this:

```
  stage('test-unit') {
            when {
                expression {
                    return shouldRunTests('yes')
                }
            }
```

however, I'm wondering how to pass the user input of either `yes` or `no` into the function? so far, it's always running the tests regardless of whether I say yes or no. I know above I have hardcoded `('yes')` that's because I saw an example do it like that. anyone care to help me how I can pass this in?

my `shouldRunTests` function just returns true or false based on the parameter passed in

Answer (score 0):

You can create "TESTS" variable before the pipeline block starts and use it in any stage, as done in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881731/8447238).