# How can I read a GIT tag from the current branch into a variable?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I want to use git tags within my declarative Jenkins pipeline. My Jenkinsfile looks like this

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Setup') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.MY_GIT_TAG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git tag -l --points-at HEAD')
                    // ... 
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build'){
            // build my code etc ....
        }
        stage('Publish') {
            // push code somewhere depending on tag
            sh "curl -X POST --upload-file ./MyDeployable https://someserver/uri/MyDeployable-${env.MY_GIT_TAG}"
        }
    }
}
```

But the environment variable `MY_GIT_TAG` was always empty. After some investigation i noticed this in my Jenkins logs:
`git fetch --no-tags --progress ...`

Is there a way to tell Jenkins to skip the `--no-tags` argument?

As i do not know beforehand how the commit is tagged i want to checkout the tag from git and use it as a variable. So the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195900/jenkins-git-plugin-how-to-build-specific-tag) is not viable here.

Comment: I don't think you can set an environment variable like that. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879733/jenkinsfile-declarative-pipeline-defining-dynamic-env-vars/43881731)

Comment: Setting the environment variable this way works. This is only one instance where it does not because there is no git tag present (the sh command returns nothing).

Comment: Could you please give more details about what you really want to do? Seems like an X Y Problem this...

Comment: I added the information. But it's nothing fancy i just want to append the git tag to the file name when i upload it somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Tai Ly there is a description of two possible solutions [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45164)

**Solution 1)**

You can create a custom checkout in your Jenkinsfile that sets `noTags` to false.

```
checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM',
    branches: scm.branches,
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: scm.doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations,
    extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false, shallow: false, depth: 0, reference: '']],
    userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs,
 ])
```

**Soltion 2)**

Add an "Advanced Clone Behaviours" entry in the branch source behaviors in the Jenkins web interface. It can also be set at the Organization/Team-level for GitHub/Bitbucket plugins & co.

Answer (score 2):

We can use, `sh(returnStdout:  true, script: "git tag --sort=-creatordate | head -n 1").trim()` take this into a variable and use it.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
    stages {
        stage('get git tag') {
            steps {
             script {
             latestTag = sh(returnStdout:  true, script: "git tag --sort=-creatordate | head -n 1").trim()
             env.BUILD_VERSION = latestTag
             echo "env-BUILD_VERSION"
             echo "${env.BUILD_VERSION}"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the `sh` returns nothing.
You can do `env.MY_GIT_TAG = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git tag -l --points-at HEAD').trim()` to return the stdout.

Comment: That is exactly what i do. But the problem is that jenkins does a `git fetch --no-tags` which means that `git tag -l --points-at HEAD` won't return anything thus `env.MY_GIT_TAG` stays empty

Comment: Have you tried to make a custom checkout before getting the tag? You can add an extension parameter where you can set the no-tag flag to false. See in: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45164

Comment: Thanks. That works. I can either create a custom checkout or another comment mentions the `Advanced Clone Behaviours` settings where i can check a `fetch tags` option.