# How to use environment variable inside Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, xl-deploy

I am having similar issue as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43879733/jenkinsfile-declarative-pipeline-defining-dynamic-env-vars/43881731)

I am trying to deploy an application via `Jenkinsfile`. For which I have to run this command on the deploy stage in *Jenkins* (if I hardcode the value then it works fine):

```
xldDeploy serverCredentials: 'usernam', environmentId: 'Environments/SysTest1/SysTest1_1', packageId: 'Applications/Testapp/testapp_1.0.4.5.Build39_TAG-test'
```

`"testapp_1.0.4.5.Build39_TAG-test"` is getting generated at running time. Which can be created by concating `"${TagVersion}.Build${env.BUILD_NUMBER}_${ComponentTagName}"`

I tried below code in my *Jenkins* pipeline:

```
stage('Deploy') {  
   node('noibuild01') {
    if ("${env.Build_WildflyCPECommon}" == 'true') {
    echo "${TagVersion}"
    echo "${ComponentTagName}"
    echo "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
    script {
                    env.buildNumber = "${TagVersion}.Build${env.BUILD_NUMBER}_${ComponentTagName}"
                    env.packageid = "'Applications/Testapp/${env.buildNumber}'"
                }
    echo "${env.buildNumber}"
    echo "${env.packageid}"
    
    xldDeploy serverCredentials: 'nex8voo', environmentId: 'Environments/SysTest1/SysTest1_1', packageId: "${env.packageid}"
    }
    }
  }
```

I checked the output, it is showing correctly:

```
echo "${env.buildNumber}" giving
testapp_1.0.4.5.Build39_TAG-test
echo "${env.packageid}" giving 
'Applications/Testapp/testapp_1.0.4.5.Build39_TAG-test'
```

But `xldDeploy serverCredentials: 'username', environmentId: 'Environments/SysTest1/SysTest1_1', packageId: "${env.packageid}"`
is taking as:

`[/repository/ci/'Applications/Testapp/testapp_1.0.4.5.Build39_TAG-test']`

Repository entity: `['Applications/Testapp/testapp_1.0.4.5.Build39_TAG-test']` *not found*

I think I can't use `packageId: "${env.packageid}"`.

Is there anything I could try? Maybe *Groovy* or *Python* code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `packageid` environment variable is not being assigned a concatenated string correctly. You have literal quotes inside the string interpolation quotes. You should change it to:

```
env.packageid = "Applications/Testapp/${env.buildNumber}"
```

to only interpolate the string, which is the functionality you want here.

Additionally, you do not need to interpolate the environment variable inside an empty string for your method parameter, so your method invocation can be cleaned up as:

```
xldDeploy serverCredentials: 'nex8voo', environmentId: 'Environments/SysTest1/SysTest1_1', packageId: env.packageid
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I was stuck here for so long. You are a life saver :)